# What meaning of this sentence?

Tags: foliations, poisson-geometry

I study about Poisson geometry. You should be know that every Poisson structure induced singular foliation. I encountered this sentence

“Two points lie in the same leaf if and only if one is accessible from the other through a composition of local homiltonian flows”

What’s meaning of right part of proposition?

Comment: What source are you using? Do you know the definition of each concept in the set {induced foliation of a Poisson manifold, leaf of a foliation, (local) Hamiltonian vector field, (local) Hamiltonian flow}? Do you know the foliation is defined (implicitly or explicitly, depending on the source) by using (local) Hamiltonian vector fields or flows?

Comment: @RicardoBuring my source is “ a brief introduction to Dirac manifold “. I know about leaf of foliation and how the poisson structure make the distribution which integral submanifold is symplectic. Also I know about definition of unique hamiltonian vector field from Piosson structure and it’s flow said hamiltonian flow. But I don’t understand how this singular leaf relate to hamiltonian vector field?

Comment: @RicardoBuring what is the meaning of one point is accessible from the other point through a composition of local flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained e.g. in section 1.3.4 *Global Structure: The Symplectic Foliation* of the book *[Poisson Structures](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642310898)* by Laurent-Gengoux, Pichereau, and Vanhaecke:

> By a *Hamiltonian path* from $m$ to $m'$ we mean a curve $\gamma$, defined on an open neighborhood of $[0,1]$, with $\gamma(0) = m$ and $\gamma(1) = m'$, which is an integral curve of a Hamiltonian vector field $\mathscr{X}_F$, where $F$ is a function, defined on an open neighborhood of $\gamma([0,1])$. More generally, when points $m_0, \ldots, m_N$ in $M$ are such that there exists a Hamiltonian path from $m_{i-1}$ to $m_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,N$, we say that there exists a *piecewise Hamiltonian path* from $m_0$ to $m_N$.

The section continues to build up to the

> **Theorem 1.30.** Every Poisson manifold $(M,\pi)$ is the disjoint union of immersed submanifolds, whose tangent spaces are spanned by the Hamiltonian vector fields of $(M,\pi)$. The Poisson structure, restricted to each of these submanifolds yields a Poisson structure of maximal rank (a symplectic structure). This decomposition is called the *symplectic foliation* of $M$ and the immersed submanifolds are called the *symplectic leaves* of $M$. For $m \in M$ the symplectic leaf which contains $m$ is given by $$\mathscr{I}_m(M) = \{m'\in M \mid \exists \text{ a piecewise Hamiltonian path in $M$ from $m$ to $m'$} \}.$$

and they remark

> The first part of the theorem can also be restated by saying that the (singular) distribution, defined by the Hamiltonian vector fields, is *integrable* (admits an integral manifold through each point).